# XSLT 1.0, copy all child nodes except some

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to copy all child nodes to a specific node, except a few. Haven't been able to get this to work? Any pointers of what I am doing wrong?

Using this XML:

```
<ns0:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <ns0:Header>
        <wsse:Sec xmlns:wsse="http://docs.x.org/wsse/"> 
            <saml:Ass xmlns:saml="http://docs.x.org/saml/">
                <ds:Sign xmlns:ds="http://docs.x.org/ds/">
                    <ds:SignVal>SignatureValue</ds:SignVal>
                </ds:Sign>
                <saml:subj>SubjectValue</saml:subj>
            </saml:Ass>
        </wsse:Sec>
        <To>http://localhost:8080/Test/</To>
        <Action>SendTest</Action>
    </ns0:Header>
    <ns0:Body>...</ns0:Body>
</ns0:Envelope>
```

The wanted result is to just get the Sec tag and all children:

```
<wsse:Sec xmlns:wsse="http://docs.x.org/wsse/"> 
   <saml:Ass xmlns:saml="http://docs.x.org/saml/">
      <ds:Sign xmlns:ds="http://docs.x.org/ds/">
         <ds:SignVal>SignatureValue</ds:SignVal>
      </ds:Sign>
      <saml:subj>SubjectValue</saml:subj>
   </saml:Ass>
</wsse:Sec>
```

I have tried numerous XSL including this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="Header">
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- Exclude these -->
    <xsl:template match="To" />
    <xsl:template match="Action" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is I get values but no tags...

Comment: ["Can someone help me?" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/162698)

Answer (score 0):

You have not accounted for namespaces in your XSLT. In your XML, `Header` is in namespace `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/`, but your XSLT is trying to match a `Header` in no namespace.

You need to declare the namespaces in your XSLT, and use them in the template matches

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                              xmlns:wsse="http://docs.x.org/wsse/">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="ns0:Header">
        <xsl:copy-of select="wsse:Sec"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns0:Body" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note this XSLT doesn't need templates matching "To" and "Action" because of the explicit copy of `wsse:Sec` using this approach. However, you do need to template to ensure any test within `ns0:Body` isn't picked up.

Another approach is to use the identity template, and then you would have the templates to exclude `To` and `Action` (and `Body`)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                              xmlns:wsse="http://docs.x.org/wsse/">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns0:Envelope|ns0:Header">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Exclude these -->
    <xsl:template match="ns0:Body|To|Action" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note there is a template matching `ns0:Envelope` and `ns0:Header` as although you don't want these elements themselves, you do need to process the child nodes.

Comment: Not sure whether these suggestions suffice as they will copy the `xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"` namespace which is in scope from the original root element. So your suggestions will output that namespace with e.g. `<wsse:Sec xmlns:wsse="http://docs.x.org/wsse/" xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">` which might not be wanted by the original poster.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use XSLT 2 or 3 with

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wsse="http://docs.x.org/wsse/"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:copy-of select="//wsse:Sec" copy-namespaces="no"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to get the posted result with a simple copy instruction: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZVw

In XSLT 1 the copy will always copy the in-scope namespace `xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"` so to remove it from the result you would need to run your code through some kind of transformation stripping in-scope namespaces (other than the one of the element itself):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wsse="http://docs.x.org/wsse/"
    exclude-result-prefixes="wsse"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@*">
      <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//wsse:Sec"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZVw/1